# Finding Average using nested queries on another table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a common problem that I was unable to solve by looking into several forums on the internet.

I have a Restaurant rating application that uses a ASP.NET WebAPI. The app has two tables Restaurant and Comments table. Each Restaurant may have several Comments and each comment has a Rating value. I am trying to put together a method in the WebAPI to pull details from the Restaurant table as well as an Average Rating value for each Restaurant by looking into the Comments table. My attempt so far is in the code below, which doesn't work. I have tried using the aggregate function, average function, nested queries, joins, etc but was still unable to pull the average value. I would be grateful if someone could help?

```
public IQueryable<RestaurantView> GetRestaurants(string All)
    {
        var query = from x in db.Restaurants
                    select new RestaurantView
                    {
                        RestaurantID = x.RestaurantID,
                        RestaurantName = x.RestaurantName,
                        RestaurantDecription = x.RestaurantDecription
                        RestaurantRatingAverage = (from a in db.Restaurants
                         join b in db.Comments on a.RestaurantID equals b.CommentsRestaurantID into z
                         from c in z
                         group c by c.CommentsRestaurantID into g
                         select new
                         {
                            RatingAverage = Convert.ToDouble(g.Average(a => a.CommentsRating))
                         };)
                    };


        return query;
    }
```

**Update: Using Jonathan's technique (see below)**

```
public IQueryable<RestaurantView> GetRestaurants(string All)
    {
        var query = from x in db.Restaurants
                    select new RestaurantView
                    {
                        RestaurantID = x.RestaurantID,
                        RestaurantName = x.RestaurantName,
                        RestaurantDecription = x.RestaurantDecription,
                        RestaurantRatingAverage = (from a in db.Comments
                   where a.CommentsRestaurantID.Equals(x.RestaurantID)select a.CommentsRating).Average()
                    };


        return query;
    }
```

but I get the following exception now

```
 An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."
```

Comment: What is the argument `All` for? I don't see it being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: Is `CommentsRating` in your `Restaurants` or `Comments` table? Currently you're trying to pull it from `Restaurants`.

Comment: @King King, I don't use the ALL parameter as of now but was planning to use in the future for a Yes or No boolean. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: @Jonathan, the CommentsRating is in the Comments table. Looking at your answer below, I believe you have figured it out already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that you can execute in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

EDIT: updated to show handling of nulls for sub query

```
void Main()
{
    var restaurants = new List<Restaurant>();
    restaurants.Add(new Restaurant(1, "McDonalds"));
    restaurants.Add(new Restaurant(2, "Wendy's"));
    restaurants.Add(new Restaurant(3, "KFC"));

    var comments = new List<Comment>();
    comments.Add(new Comment(1, 1, "I love clowns!", 9.5));
    comments.Add(new Comment(2, 1, "Disgusting", 1.0));
    comments.Add(new Comment(3, 1, "Average", 5.0));
    comments.Add(new Comment(4, 2, "Hmmm tasty", 8.5));
    comments.Add(new Comment(5, 2, "Yuck", 4.0));

    // Edit - removed comment for KFC, updated code below to handle nulls
    var restaurantsWithRatings = restaurants.Select(r => new {
            RestaurantId = r.RestaurantId,
            Name = r.Name,
            Rating = (
                comments.Where(c => c.RestaurantId == r.RestaurantId)
                    .Select(c => c.Rating)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
            ).Average()
        });

    foreach(var r in restaurantsWithRatings)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", r.Name, r.Rating);
}

class Restaurant
{
    public Restaurant(int restaurantId, string name)
    {
        RestaurantId = restaurantId;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Comment
{
    public Comment(int commentId, int restaurantId, string message, double rating)
    {
        CommentId = commentId;
        RestaurantId = restaurantId;
        Message = message;
        Rating = rating;
    }

    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Having a look at your example, I have implemented something similar, I have copied my updated code as part of the Question but I get an error still on the returned data being null. The Average is of type Double, I have tried Convert.ToDouble() but that hasnt resolved the issue :(

Comment: @Piranha86 I've updated the code, use of DefaultIfEmpty should help you.